# Unpack dotNetReactor and VM Protect

Tags: c#, .net, reverse-engineering, отладчик

Пытаюсь понять реально вообще это распаковать с помощью дебаггера dnSpy и dbg32/64=)

```
-=[ ProtectionID v0.6.9.0 DECEMBER]=-
[!] [.net scan core] dotNetReactor detected!
[!] VM Protect  detected ! // Версия 3.3.4
```

[image: AddressOfEntryPoint]

[image: Section Headers]

[image: dbg64]

И почему dbg64 не видит Section Headers=)
И если это возможно, то в каком порядке нужно распаковывать данную программу?
Видно, что сделано продуманно, но и информацию в интернете найти не могу.

Comment: Я не понимаю, что именно и чем вы хотите распаковать, у меня все перепуталось, пока читал вопрос.

Comment: @aepot Программа calc64.exe. Распаковать с помощью dbg64 и в каком порядке. Но сначало почему нету Section Headers в dbg64. Из за того что там нету `calc64 .text .sdata .vmp0 .vmp1 .rsrc` я не смогу достать код=) Но я догадываюсь, что это находится на 3 скрине, там где Type начинается с IMG, но я нигде в интернете такое не видел. И AddressOfEntryPoint -> 00000000, но там должно быть другое значение, поэтому возможно и не видно!

Comment: Упаковывают программу с защитой не просто так. Я не думаю что тут место для обсуждения взлома защиты программы. Если хотите что то изменить - обратитесь к автору программы.

Comment: Привет @Геннадий П данная программа является запрещённой, я её взламываю не для вреда кому то, а понять как она работает в образовательных целях. Но я уже догадался, где скрывается заголовок файла, проблема только в том, что она упакована несколько раз)